# Disable Enterprise feature on all site collections except one

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

How could we disable Enterprise feature on all site collections in a farm, except on one site collection?

Is it possible at all?

Comment: please read: disable all Enterprise features on all site collections in a farm except one site collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with PowerShell.

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ea SilentlyContinue

$excludeSite = "http://servername/sites/siteToExclude"

$spWebApp = Get-SPWebApplication

foreach($site in $spWebApp.Sites)
{
    if ($site.url -ne $excludeSite)
    {
        $siteUrl = $site.url
        Write-Host "Going into SiteCollection $siteurl"
        Disable-SPFeature -identity "SharePoint Server Enterprise Site Collection features"
        Write-Host "Disabling feature in SiteCollection $siteurl"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In *Site Actions --> Site Collection Features* of each site collection, you can disable a feature called **SharePoint Server Enterprise Site Collection features** on all site collections except in the one where you want to have these features enabled.